# Mongoose Populate - how can you dynamically or programmatic perform field selection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query 1 which return an array of records, let's say activityList from activitySchema. Now On this activityList array, I am trying to use populate to populate user Information. I would like to dynamically select fields based on the certain activity type. Here is my schema since each sub-document has many fields.

```
var activitySchema = new Schema({
    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'}
    , updateDt: {type: Date, Default: Date.now()}
    , activityType: String
    , weight: Number
    , activityAttributes: [String]
});
```

users schema has many sub-documents like

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
      auth: authSchema
    , membership: membershipSchema
    , personal: personalSchema
    , location: locationSchema
    , religion: religionSchema});
```

based on the activity type value let's say "PERSONAL", "LOCATION" & "RELIGION" populate should only return those values.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no can do with the schema you have.

You can query the activitySchema object, examine the activityType, then query the userSchema selecting only the fields you want based on the activity type: PERSONAL, LOCATION, RELIGION. So you can proceed with two queries instead of one.

You could also grab them all with populate and then filter out the props you don't want in javascript.  You would still need to send all of that data over the network to your calling code.  But maybe you save some bandwidth if the above code shunts the data someplace else (like a browser).

Without knowing more about what you are trying to accomplish I can't advise you on a better way to model your data. Potentially breaking up the userSchema is probably something to consider. There's no doubt that if you put in the time you can have a data model that gets you everything in one shot.

Comment: thank you for your response. I am using a cloud service provider (mlab) for mongodb and my application is running on EC2, I wanted to avoid unnecessary network data transfer between application server and db. Breaking up my schema would be a huge effort.